# More Select together

Tags: sql, select, join

can you help me with this problem? I need join these three SELECT together...........It is possible? I need one table... with collums:jmeno, Pocet_zapasu,branek,Pocet_zapasu2,branek2,Pocet_turnaju,branek3.

```
/*Soutezni zapasy*/
SELECT
    Jmeno,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Pocet_zapasu,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as branek
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas 
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Zapas_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' AND(Zapas.Druh=1)
GROUP BY Jmeno;

/*Pratelske zapasy*/
SELECT
    Jmeno,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Pocet_zapasu2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as branek2
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas 
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Zapas_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' AND(Zapas.Druh=2)
GROUP BY Jmeno;

/*turnaje*/
SELECT
    Jmeno,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Pocet_turnaju,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as branek3
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Turnaj ON Ucast_Turnaj.ID_Hrace_turnaj=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Turnaj ON Turnaj.ID_turnaj=Ucast_Turnaj.ID_turnaje_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Turnaj.Kategorie_Turnaj 
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Turnaj_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Turnaj_Datum < '9/1/2014'
GROUP BY Jmeno;
```

Comment: Put each select into a temp table and join them on Jmeno

Comment: How into a temp table?

Comment: You could do a union query.

Comment: What database engine are you using?  Check to see if it supports UNION.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? if MSSQL then `SELECT * INTO #tmp1 FROM tbl1; SELECT * INTO #tmp2 FROM tbl2; SELECT * FROM #tmp1 INNER JOIN #tmp2 ON #tmp2.id = #tmp1.id; DROP TABLE #tmp1; DROP TABLE #tmp2`

Comment: I don't think OP wants to UNION these results.  OP is asking for different columns -- a UNION would return these in the same column.

Comment: I think `CROSS JOIN` is a good choice for you. You can try my answer below, and feedback me whether it works for you or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can combine your first 2 queries and just use add to your `CASE` statements.  I am not sure about your third, so instead of trying to combine it, I just added it as a subquery and used a `LEFT JOIN` for it:

```
SELECT
    Jmeno,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' AND Zapas.Druh=1 then 1 end) as Pocet_zapasu,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky> 0AND Zapas.Druh=1 then Branky end) as branek,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' AND Zapas.Druh=2 then 1 end) as Pocet_zapasu2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 AND Zapas.Druh=2 then Branky end) as branek2,
    Pocet_turnaju,
    branek3
FROM Hraci
    INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace 
    INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast 
    INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            Jmeno,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Pocet_turnaju
            SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as branek3
        FROM Hraci
            INNER JOIN Ucast_Turnaj ON Ucast_Turnaj.ID_Hrace_turnaj=Hraci.IDHrace 
            INNER JOIN Turnaj ON Turnaj.ID_turnaj=Ucast_Turnaj.ID_turnaje_ucast 
            INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Turnaj.Kategorie_Turnaj 
        WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Turnaj_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Turnaj_Datum < '9/1/2014'
        GROUP BY Jmeno
    ) t ON Hraci.Jmeno = t.Jmeno
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) 
    AND Zapas_Datum >= '1/1/2013' 
    AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' 
    AND Zapas.Druh IN (1,2)
GROUP BY Jmeno;
```

Without fully understanding your table structure, you may be able to consolidate this further.  Also, wasn't sure which table you were pulling Jmeno from -- I assumed Hraci.

From my understanding of your question, you do not want to use `UNION` as that will not create additional columns, just additional rows.  For example `SELECT 1 as Col1 UNION SELECT 2` will return a single column with 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM   
((SELECT
    Jmeno,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' THEN 1 END) AS Pocet_zapasu,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 THEN Branky END) AS branek
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas 
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Zapas_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' AND(Zapas.Druh=1)
GROUP BY Jmeno
) AS a CROSS JOIN



(SELECT   
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' THEN 1 END) AS Pocet_zapasu2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 THEN Branky END) AS branek2
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas 
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Zapas_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' AND(Zapas.Druh=2)
GROUP BY Jmeno
) AS b CROSS JOIN



(SELECT           
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' THEN 1 END) AS Pocet_turnaju,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 THEN Branky END) AS branek3
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Turnaj ON Ucast_Turnaj.ID_Hrace_turnaj=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Turnaj ON Turnaj.ID_turnaj=Ucast_Turnaj.ID_turnaje_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Turnaj.Kategorie_Turnaj 
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Turnaj_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Turnaj_Datum < '9/1/2014'
GROUP BY Jmeno
) AS c)
```

Tested on mySQL, it should get rid of the error now

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.

Comment: Answer edited, add alias for each select. Please try again and feedback me :D

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 40
Incorrect syntax near '3'.

Comment: the column Jmeno is there 3 times...but no data..:/

Comment: Try to run each query to see if they run properly, and remove the Jmeno in query 2 and 3 :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a UNION ALL between each SQL query.
By placing a UNION ALL it will have the result of each query and display it together. For this to work each query must have the same number of columns and column names.

EDIT: I have edited the column names to be the same.
EDIT: I have removed the semicolon from the group by which was breaking the query.

```
SELECT
    Jmeno as Column1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Column2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as Column3
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas 
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Zapas_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' AND(Zapas.Druh=1)
GROUP BY Jmeno

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Jmeno as Column1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Column2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as Column3
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas 
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Zapas_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' AND(Zapas.Druh=2)
GROUP BY Jmeno

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Jmeno as Column1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Column2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as Column3
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Turnaj ON Ucast_Turnaj.ID_Hrace_turnaj=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Turnaj ON Turnaj.ID_turnaj=Ucast_Turnaj.ID_turnaje_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Turnaj.Kategorie_Turnaj 
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Turnaj_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Turnaj_Datum < '9/1/2014'
GROUP BY Jmeno
```

Comment: After that I have this error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: I have fixed the query. The semicolon beside the group by was breaking it.

Comment: Also i just reread your question and this wont work for you as you want more than 3 columns. This will put all results into the same 3 columns.

Comment: You have write column 2 and Column3 with 3 select, but in each select these column are something different...in first select is the league matches, in second friendly matches and in last is tournament...

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.jmeno, A.Pocet_zapasu,A.branek,B.Pocet_zapasu2,B.branek2,C.Pocet_turnaju,C.branek3
FROM
    (SELECT
        Jmeno,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Pocet_zapasu,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as branek
    FROM Hraci
    INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace 
    INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast 
    INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas 
    WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Zapas_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' AND(Zapas.Druh=1)
    GROUP BY Jmeno
    ) a
INNER JOIN  
    /*Pratelske zapasy*/
    (SELECT
        Jmeno,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Pocet_zapasu2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as branek2
    FROM Hraci
    INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace 
    INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast 
    INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas 
    WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Zapas_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' AND(Zapas.Druh=2)
    GROUP BY Jmeno
    ) B
    ON A.Jmeno = B.Jmeno
INNER JOIN 
    (/*turnaje*/
    SELECT
        Jmeno,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Pocet_turnaju,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>0 then Branky end) as branek3
    FROM Hraci
    INNER JOIN Ucast_Turnaj ON Ucast_Turnaj.ID_Hrace_turnaj=Hraci.IDHrace 
    INNER JOIN Turnaj ON Turnaj.ID_turnaj=Ucast_Turnaj.ID_turnaje_ucast 
    INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Turnaj.Kategorie_Turnaj 
    WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Turnaj_Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Turnaj_Datum < '9/1/2014'
    GROUP BY Jmeno
    ) C
ON A.Jmeno = C.Jmeno
```

Comment: Now a I have all columns, but in these columns aren´t any value..:/ When i have 3 selected separate, a have a lot of values...:/